# ASP.NET MVC 3 file upload plugins

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-plugins, asyncfileupload, multifile-uploader

I'm looking for a multifile upload module / plugin, preferably async upload for my ASP.NET MVC 3 project. I've come across blueimp but after fiddling around with the demo, some images uploaded were not shown in the preview section.

Are there any more good async multi file upload plugins that anyone could recommend?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7784168/asynchronous-file-uploader-with-mvc3-net ?

Answer (score 3):

Try [plupload](http://www.plupload.com/). It's well documented.

Comment: Looks promising. Will try out more. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check [Telerik Upload for ASP.NET MVC](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/upload). [It's free under GPL V2](http://www.telerik.com/purchase/faqs/aspnet-mvc.aspx). A commercial version is also available.

Comment: As this is a project for commercial purposes, GPL license is not applicable. I've checked out their demo, the only downside is that they don't sell by plugins, they sell the entire package and many of those are unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can use plugin [ajax upload](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/)

This is some it's features:

1. multiple file select, progress-bar in FF, Chrome, Safari
2. drag-and-drop file select in FF, Chrome uploads are cancellable no
3. external dependencies doesn't use Flash fully working with https
4. keyboard support in FF, Chrome, Safari tested in IE7,8; Firefox 3,3.6,4; Safari4,5; Chrome; Opera10.60;